# Mixing IoC container use with "poor mans" DI

Tags: object-oriented, python, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I'm finding the use of IoC containers to be quite the shift in my application design, and its for the better.  I'm using a framework called [`injector`](https://pypi.org/project/injector/) that aims to mimic (albeit not entirely) the Guice framework.

With that in mind, I have 4 classes that I'd like to outline that show where my mixing of container use and "poor mans" (manual) DI take place:

```
@singleton
class App:

    @inject
    def __init__(self, config: Config, logger: Logger) -> None:
        self.config = config
        self.logger = logger

@singleton
class Config:

    def __init__(self, path) -> None:
        self.path = path

@singleton
class Logger:

    def __init__(self, path) -> None:
        self.path = path

@singleton
class Client:

    def __init__(self, config: Config, logger: Logger) -> None:
        self.config = config
        self.logger = logger
```

In production I use a module to tell the container how to instantiate `Config` and `Logger`:

```
class AppModule(module):

    CONFIG_PATH = '/foo/bar/settings.config'
    LOGGER_PATH = '/foo/bar/logs'

    @provider
    def provide_config(self) -> Config:
        return Config(CONFIG_PATH)

    @provider
    def provide_logger(self) -> Logger:
        return Logger(LOGGER_PATH)
```

The entry point of the program looks like this:

```
from program import App
from program import AppModule

if __name__ == '__main__':

    injector = Injector(AppModule)
    app = injector.get(App)
    app.start()
```

Now the `start` method for the `App` class would in practice look as:

```
def start(self) -> None:
    self.config.load()
    Client(self.config, self.logger).run()  # is a blocking operation for a GUI to run
    self.end()

def end(self) -> None:
    self.config.save()
```

It is the `start` method that "poor mans" DI takes place. I never define to the IoC container how a `Client` object is instantiated (hence no `@inject`) and it uses the same singleton `Config` and `Logger` that `App` uses. The IoC container is responsible for injecting the appropriate dependencies into the `App` class, but afterwards I explicitly pass them to a new instance of `Client`. I do this because `App` does not depend on `Client` (right?) given that none of its member functions ever need to reference it again beyond `start`.

If I were to define it in the IoC container (through `AppModule`) I would have to somehow reference the `Injector` instance inside `App` which would mean passing it around. To my knowledge, Guice discourages this and it is bad practice for DI.

Therefore, is it normal or problematic to use manual DI in tandem with an IoC container?

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to address some points you make in your post before answering your question more directly :

> I do this because App does not depend on Client (right?) given that none of its member functions ever need to reference it again beyond start.

False. `App` is completely dependent on `Client`, since it cannot work without it! If you delete `Client` right now, your app simply won't run, since `App` is missing its dependency. It doesn't look that way because you made your `Client` a Singleton, and pull a reference from it only in `App.start`, but don't be mistaken : it is still a direct dependency.

> If I were to define it in the IoC container (through AppModule) I would have to somehow reference the Injector instance inside App which would mean passing it around. To my knowledge, Guice discourages this and it is bad practice for DI.

It is bad practice to reference the injector in your code, doing so would simply make it a  [Service Locator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), which defeats the purpose of using the framework. I think you're too focused on doing the DI yourself for `Client`. What if we did use your DI framework to wire up `Client`? Then :

```py
@singleton
class Client:

    @inject
    def __init__(self, config: Config, logger: Logger) -> None:
        self.config = config
        self.logger = logger
```

You (probably) don't even need to do anything else, since you already wrote your providers for `Config` and `Logger`.

Then, in `App.start`, simply pass in an instance of `Client` :

```py
def start(self, client: Client) -> None:
    self.config.load()
    client.run()
    self.end()
```

Since `App` only needs `Client` for its `start` method.

Personnally, I'd probably go with making `client` a member of `App`, and letting your DI framework do the wiring :

```py
@singleton
class App:

    @inject
    def __init__(self, config: Config, logger: Logger, client: Client) -> None:
        self.config = config
        self.logger = logger
        self.client = client
```

Then you'd just have to use `self.client` in `App.start`, and the dependency `App -> Client` would be clearer in my opinion, but your mileage may vary.

> Therefore, is it normal or problematic to use manual DI in tandem with an IoC container?

At least in my experience, it's not frequent to want to do manual DI while also using a DI framework/library. It does lead to some problems, as you have encountered. The framework is there to do this job for you, so if you want to do that job manually too, you're bound to run into some trouble with the framework. For your case, I'd simply let `Client` be injected by the framework, and that should solve your problems for now.

But I'd also look into removing all those pesky `@singleton` too, since they cause a lot more problem than they solve and you can setup your whole application with only one copy of each of your classes through your DI framework.